# Can't figure out why I get TypeError while fetching JSON with JS

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

To be fair, I'm a bit stumped how to even research on such case. 'Functions are not running but manually works?' I've been trying to implenet async/await functions yesterday but i couldn't even make it work either. Sorry for asking such basic question but I've been stuck here for days and can't move on forward. *Hope I'd get some reply this time.*

On this scenario I have a external JSON file where I store objects in an array with every object has it's own `provider, id, category, description`

I'm trying to implement this scenario;

1) fetch the json and assign it to `archive` as an array with `fetchArchive()`

2) pick a random json  and assign it to upNext `randomiser()`

3) set up the dom attribute values depending on the upNext's values with `setUpDOM()`

But when I ran the code I get an type error saying that upNext on Firefox, provider on chrome is undefined.

I can see that functions are not running for some reason. But if I ran the codes manually from console they do work as I intended.

```js
let upNext
let archive = []

function fetchArchive() { 
   fetch('./js/archive.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => { archive = data; })
};

// == Randomiser ==
fetchArchive();


function randomiser() {
  upNext = archive[Math.floor(Math.random()*archive.length)] 
}

randomiser();

// == DOM Setup ==


function setUpDOM() {
  document.getElementById('player').setAttribute('data-plyr-provider', upNext.provider)
  document.getElementById('player').setAttribute('data-plyr-embed-id', upNext.id)
  let titles = document.getElementsByClassName('videoTitle');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(titles, function(element) {
    element.innerHTML = upNext.title;
  });
}
setUpDOM();
```

and the JSON that I'm fetching

```
[
    {
      "provider": "youtube",
      "id": "RYpqE0_VpWA",
      "category": "Music",
      "title": "Ratatat - Party With Children",
      "descrtiption": "Ipsum Lorem Consectetur adipisicing elit."
    },
    {
      "provider": "vimeo",
      "id": "420049165",
      "category": "Music",
      "title": "Boy I Never Knew",
      "descrtiption": "Lorem ipsum Consectetur adipisicing"
    }
]
```

Just to note this json file probably going to have thousand objects. I'm not if this type of randomization would work on such long array objects.

I'm open for any kind of different approaches as this is my personal project. Can share the full code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions are running, but `fetch` is asynchronous, so `archive` is empty when you run the `Randomizer` and so it puts nothing in the `upNext` variable.

You will need to wait for the `fetch` to complete before calling the rest.

```js
let upNext
let archive = []

function fetchArchive() {
  fetch('./js/archive.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      archive = data;
      randomiser();
      setUpDOM();
    })
};

// == Randomiser ==
function randomiser() {
  upNext = archive[Math.floor(Math.random() * archive.length)]
}

// == DOM Setup ==
function setUpDOM() {
  document.getElementById('player').setAttribute('data-plyr-provider', upNext.provider)
  document.getElementById('player').setAttribute('data-plyr-embed-id', upNext.id)
  let titles = document.getElementsByClassName('videoTitle');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(titles, function(element) {
    element.innerHTML = upNext.title;
  });
}


fetchArchive();
```

Comment: Oh, that worked thanks very much! I didn't knew I could add more than one assignee but that makes a ton sense though. So within .then I can do pretty much anything like it was a function deceleration, isn't it? 

(sorry for asking the basics, I've start learning development like two weeks ago, pretty much everything is new to me)

Comment: @Korhan it **is** a function declaration. The syntax in your code is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). It could well be a normal function `.then(function(data){ ... })`

Answer (score 0):

when you invoke`randomiser`, the `fetchArchive` is still fetching, you should chain the `randomiser` call to the the end of  `fetchArchive`

ie

```
let upNext
let archive = []

function fetchArchive() { 
   return fetch('./js/archive.json') // returns
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => { archive = data; }) // this Promise
};


// == Randomiser ==

function randomiser() {
  upNext = archive[Math.floor(Math.random()*archive.length)] 
}


// == DOM Setup ==


function setUpDOM() {
  document.getElementById('player').setAttribute('data-plyr-provider', upNext.provider)
  document.getElementById('player').setAttribute('data-plyr-embed-id', upNext.id)
  let titles = document.getElementsByClassName('videoTitle');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(titles, function(element) {
    element.innerHTML = upNext.title;
  });
}


fetchArchive().then(randomiser).then(setUpDOM)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've also tried the chain the callbacks like that. That also gives me an error saying that `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` :(

Comment: I think that this is because ```fetchArchive``` have to *return* a **Promise** in order to append an handler to his ```then```, as you can see I have indeed returned a **Promise** (returned itself from the then chained to the fetch)

Comment: oh,  didn't noticed you've made a **return** before fetch. Now it work's but I'm a bit confused more how did that just works. When you return something from a function, does scope chain waits for it's return? sorry for coming up with a follow up question.